# ffmpeg conversion from MOV to mp4 - how to conserve creation date

Tags: ffmpeg, icloud

Windows 10 1909, latest updates.

I am helping a friend move his photos and videos from one Apple ID to another.
I have downloaded all items to my PC using iCloud for PC. I then proceeded to re-upload all the photos to the new Apple ID.
2'000 of the videos are MOV, which I cannot upload to iCloud. I seem to need to convert them to mp4 in order to upload them.

I have converted all of the MOVs to mp4 using the following batch

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.MOV') DO ffmpeg -i "%%G" -f mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec mp3 "%%~nG.mp4"
```

This worked fine and I managed to upload the (now) mp4's to iCloud. Unfortunately all the mp4's now carry yesterday's date as creation date. In iCloud (and on the iPad) all the videos are now displayed with a creation date of 12.6.2020 and it is impossible to find a particular video. Also the context to the photos is lost.

Question:

- Is there any way to (batch) convert 2'000 MOV to mp4 while preserving the creation date?
- alternatively: is there any way to upload the original MOV files to iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a utility like [touch](https://superuser.com/questions/10426/windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-touch) or use powershell to copy the timestamp from the source mov to the destination mp4. Using touch, it would look like `touch "%%~nG.mp4" -r "%%G"` when you use the same for loop.

Comment: Thanks @wimh , in the meantime I found a way to do it in with ffmpeg

Comment: Question was ambiguous and apparently it was about `creation_time` MP4 metadata, but this answer will address the time of the file itself.

Answer (score 1):

The follwing seems to work:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.MOV') DO ffmpeg -i "%%G" -f mp4 -map_metadata 0 -vcodec copy -acodec mp3 "Converted\%%~nG.mp4"
```

-map_metadata 0 transfers the global metadata from the MOV to the mp4 file. The mp4s now have correct creation dates and iCloud sorts them under the correct date (at least the first 50 that I uploaded)